# angular-ivh-treeview: transmit the on-cb-change callback to my custom template node?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, treeview

How do I transmit the on-cb-change callback to my custom template node?

Everything is working fine when i'm only using the directive ivh-treeview-on-cb-change. But whenever I want to add a custom template the directive doesn't work.

What can be the problem?

```
<div ivh-treeview="stuff" 
     ivh-treeview-on-cb-change="myfunc(ivhNode, ivhIsSelected, ivhTree)">
         <script type="text/ng-template">
             <span ivh-treeview-toggle>
                 <span ivh-treeview-twistie></span>
             </span>
             <ascii-box></ascii-box>
             <span class="ivh-treeview-node-label" 
                   ivh-treeview-toggle>
                       {{trvw.label(node)}}
             </span>
             <div ivh-treeview-children></div>
         </script>
</div>




$scope.myfunc = function (ivhNode, ivhIsSelected, ivhTree) {
    console.log(ivhNode, ivhIsSelected, ivhTree);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're running into is that inline templates do not have access to a transcluded scope. I.e. the scope your template has access to does not inherit from the scope you're attaching functions to.

This is being added as a feature in the v2 release of ivh-treeview (currently accessible as an alpha release).

In v1.x of treeview your best bet will be to broadcast/emit events for communication in and out of templates.

Of note:

- https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/pull/158
- https://github.com/iVantage/angular-ivh-treeview/issues/81